# Google playstore does not identify the new package name?

Tags: android, google-play

I created an app using Android Studio. And linked firebase as backend. While publishing on play store google informs me that there is another app with the same package name. So I go back and change the package name in and AndroidManifest file and rebuild the apk. On uploading, the apk google still says the same error with an old package name. I read somewhere that we have to change the applicationId in a build.gradle file also, but this id is used by firebase to identify the app. Hence I can't do this , so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you should create a new application in your developer google console to upload your application with the new package name. You can't modify a package name after upload an application:

> Things That Cannot Change:
>
> The most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package name,”
>   the unique name you give to your application in its
>   AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming
>   convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name
>   collisions. For example, since Google owns the domain “google.com”,
>   the manifest package names of all of our applications should start
>   with “com.google.” It’s important for developers to follow this
>   convention in order to avoid conflicts with other developers.
>
> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Comment: I have not yet uploaded the app so package name can be changed,so thats not the problem. The fact that playstore is not reading the manifest file for the new name is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change applicationId with same package name in build.gradle file.
In  android studio applicationId is considered as package name for play store. so change applicationId to change package name. It will help you.

Comment: So do i have to create a new application in firebase becuase the firebase cloud still understands the old package name